# Angular2 - Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'xyz

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular 2 app and I am iterating through some records and displaying a table. My code looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows......">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <span placement="right" [innerHTML]="row[column.name]" container="body"
                [tooltip] = "(cell.offsetWidth < cell.scrollWidth ) ? (row[column.name]) : ''" container="body">
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

When I am doing this check to decide to display tooltip content in the loop as shown above, I get the following error when values changes for the tooltip:

"Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'xyz...'. at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (eval at

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try migrating the tertiary statement to a function in the class, rather than in the template. Often times I've seen that Angular doesn't handle changed values of variables (or complex statements) in the template, so passing those values to the template/view from a function works fairly well.

Yes, you can just pass all the values you want to use to determine the value of your tooltip into the function, and just return the value you want.